# Why the difference in how Inherits works in the WebForm?

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, webforms

I stumbled on something that surprised me.  I'm migrating a couple of WebForms from a common web project into two different web projects.  The projects are treating the Inherits tag (in the source / HTML view) differently.

Take this example: `SomeWonderfulPage.aspx` / `SomeWonderfulPage.aspx.cs`

The code-behind is totally standard (and no namespace):

```
public partial class SomeWonderfulPage : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
  //...
}
```

In one project `Inherits="SomeWonderfulPage"` works and `Inherits="MyNameSpace.Blah.SomeWonderfulPage"` fails (intellisense can't see the Label controls, and the project won't build); and in the other project it's the other way around.

I confirmed the behavior by making new WebForms in both projects via the 'Add New Item...' command in VS2008 - same results.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Are you sure that the assembly containing SomeWonderfulPage is referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I copied the web pages from the first site (into which I had refactored the webforms) into the second site the SomeWonderfulPage.designer.cs files came across but weren't included in the project by default.

In such cases I found (on further exploration) that I couldn't get either `Inherit` to work.

Including the designer files fixed it.  Doh.